# Unable to use dtype in Python even after importing numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

```
from numpy import *

arr = ([1,2,3,4,5])

print(arr.dtype)
```

I have written this program but when I am trying to use `dtype` I'm getting this below error, please suggest why this is happening and how can I check the type:

> print(arr.dtype)
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Comment: Use import numpy as np, arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]), np.dtype(arr) if you wish to use numpy.

Comment: Your `arr` is a list. List is not a numpy type and does not have a `dtype` field.

Comment: Its working now, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

You did not create a numpy array, just a classic python list

```
from numpy import array

arr = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(arr.dtype)  # int32
```

---

Also avoid importing `*`, prefer the explicit imports

Comment: @SaheliNag You may think about [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to reward those how helped you, or at least comment to explain what's missing ;)